# Focusing Textbox in a DataGrid on Checked Event of a CheckBox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have two tasks that need to be done when a check box is checked. This check box is defined in a DataGrid (which is bound to a collection) as a data template of DataGridTemplateColumn. 
Also, there is a DataGridTemplateColumn with data template of text box.
On checked event of a check box, I have to clear the text of the text box on the same row and also set the focus on that text box. 
Clearing the text works fine on using the EventTrigger. 
Problem is the second part where I have to set the focus on the text box. 
TO achieve this goal, I thought to use attached behavior with ChangePropertyAction.
For this, I created a dependency property, hoping to get the reference of the datagrid and finding the text box on which focus needs to be set (which I'll do later).

```
public class TestDependencyProperty : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        FlagCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "FlagChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(TestDependencyProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var datagrid = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
        //get the textbox from the datagrid on which focus
        //has to set and set the focus
    }

    public static bool GetFlagChecked(
        DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(FlagCheckedProperty);
    }
    public static void SetFlagChecked(
        DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(FlagCheckedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

and here is the xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FlagCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="5" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" v:TestDependencyProperty.FlagChecked="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Non Kittable" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Flag,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.FlaggedCheckedCommand}" 
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    <isc:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" PropertyName="FlagChecked" Value="True"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tracking No." Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding XTrackingNum,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

But, on checking the check box I get error saying, "Cannot find a property named "v:TestDependencyProperty.FlagChecked" on type "DataGrid"

I also tried binding in this way 
     
, but it didn't work -
"Cannot find a property named "FlagChecked" on type "DataGrid".

Not sure if this is the right way to do this. 
Can someone point me in right direction..?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by adding a boolean property "FocusOnChecked" to the class whose collection is getting binded to the datagrid and setting property as true or false on checked and unchecked event of checkbox using ChangePropertyAction.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.FlaggedCheckedCommand}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                <isc:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding}" PropertyName="FocusOnChecked" Value="True"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                    <isc:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding}" PropertyName="FocusOnChecked" Value="False"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then created a attached property for textbox and binded it with the new property.

```
 public class FocusBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        FocusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Focus",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(FocusBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var txtBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        if (txtBox == null)
            return;
        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;
        if ((bool )dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue)
            txtBox.Focus();
    }

    public static bool GetFocus(
        DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(FocusProperty);
    }
    public static void SetFocus(
        DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(FocusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

below is the xaml for textbox.

```
 <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox vm:FocusBehavior.Focus="{Binding Path= FocusOnChecked}" Text="{Binding TrackingNum,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >    
    </TextBox>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xaml.cs you have set the focus of the textbox.
Create an event on checkbox when it is checked.

```
<CheckBox Name="sampleChkbox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Flag" Checked="sampleChkbox_Checked"/>
<TextBox Name="txtSample" Grid.Row="2" Width="200px" Height="40"/>

     xaml.cs
     private void sampleChkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        if((bool)chk.IsChecked)
            txtSample.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: This solution will not work as this checkbox and textbox are part of CellTemplate of a datagrid which is bound to a collection. Naming the checkbox and textbox would not solve the problem as both these controls will be generated dynamically depending upon the collection.